# Source for problems to practice applying Zorn's lemma.

Tags: induction, set-theory, problem-solving, transfinite-induction

I have been stuck trying to prove things too many times to mention, where the idea I needed to use was Zorn's lemma.  I would like to get to the point where applying transfinite induction is a natural to me as using normal induction.  Is there a collection of problems (say on the beginner graduate student level) that use Zorn's lemma?

Comment: In algebra, one generally uses Zorn's Lemma to prove the existence of maximal objects. Like maximal subgroups, maximal ideals etc (note that there are groups without any maximal subgroups or rings without maximal ideals).

Comment: Any filter on a set can be extended to a  maximal filter (ultra-filter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some problems that uses Zorn's lemma.

1) Every nonzero commutative ring contains a maximal ideal.

2) If every prime ideal in a commutative ring is finitely generated then every ideal in the ring is finitely generated.

3) Every nonzero vector space contains a basis.

You can find more problems here: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/zorn1.pdf

Comment: It is consistent with $ZF+\neg AC$ that there exists a vector space with two cardinally incomparable Hamel bases. So I suggest using Zorn's Lemma  to prove  that all bases for a vector space are cardinally equivalent to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about Zorn's lemma in the title and in the body also about transfinite induction. These are two related topics, but they are not the same. Anyway, you can find a chapter on each of these two topics (including some problems and their solutions) in the book [Komjath P.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9ter_Komj%C3%A1th), [Totik V.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilmos_Totik): *Problems and Theorems in Classical Set Theory,* Springer-Verlag, 2006; [author's website](http://web.cs.elte.hu/~kope/setproblems.html), [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=HGF3jkEaI-wC).

Answer (score 0):

Since Zorn's lemma is equivalent to the axiom of choice, you can find many examples on the [wikipedia page on AC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice#Equivalents).